# sum numbers in for loop, batch file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I need to make a for loop that sums up numbers from 1 to x where x is users input number.
I know how to make the for loop and display those numbers but I don't know how to sum them at the same time.

FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,%x%) DO ( echo %%x

)

Comment: `set /A sum=x*(x+1)/2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do arithmetics, use `set /a`. Also use delayed expansion to use the variable inside a block (between `(` and `)`)

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set sum=0
FOR /L %%x IN (1,1,%x%) DO ( 
  set /a sum=!sum!+%%x
  echo + %%x = !sum!
)
```

Comment: You do not need to expand variables within SET /A statements: `set /a sum=sum+%%x` works just fine. You can also use `set /a sum+=%%x`. However, the delayed expansion is needed as shown in your ECHO statement.